# Get values of form field in javascript from a visualforce page

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

i have requirement where i need to check if  apex:inputCheckbox  is checked, and if it isn't then raise an alert saying that its not checked.

```
 <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!check}"/>
```

I am raising the alert from a java script. i am using actionfunction to call a apex method after the alert is raised.

What i need is a way to check if the checkbox is checked or not in javascript

Thanks

Prady

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just give it an id, then use `document.getElementById()` to grab it:

```
<apex:inputCheckbox id="theCheckBox" value="{!Contact.Some_Checkbox__c}" onClick="alert('checked? ' + document.getElementById('{!$Component.theCheckBox}').checked);"/>
```

Note that if it's inside other elements with you may need to drill down to it, so if it was inside an `<apex:pageBlockSection>` with `id="theSection"` then you'd need:

```
document.getElementById('{!$Component.theSection.theCheckBox}');
```

Whether you need to do this or not depends on where your javascript is in the page with relation to the checkbox. Good luck!